# Alfresco configurations

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configuration, alfresco

Is there a way to automatically refresh the changes I made in my java classes once I ran my alfresco repository in eclipse ? 
Because it is very time consuming to stop my tomcat, make changes in my classes and re run it then test the changes I made.

Is there a way to configure it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is way, If you are using SDK 3.0 you need to configura hotswap agent.

Below link will help you in that.

https://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/sdk-hot-reload-hotswap.html

You can configure hotswap agent in eclipse also.same add same configuration in eclipse (Run Configuration->Maven Build->New Build)

- add goals as clean install alfresco:run
- In jre tab add this configuration In VM arguments field ==> -javaagent:[path]hotswap-agent.jar
- Run it.

In case of SDK 2.0 you need to use spring-loaded jar instead of hotswap agent.Configuration steps are almost same except the goals.

Comment: If you have trouble with hotswap agent and you can justify the expense, JRebel also works with SDK 3.0.